# Did the brain anatomists and psychophysicists of the early to mid 1800s make any philosophical speculations on the nature of emotions and cognition?

Tags: biographical-details, philosophy-of-science

I was wondering if the psychophysicists and brain anatomists from 1800 up until 1860s made any novel, noteworthy philosophical speculations about the emotions and cognition.If they did is there any evidence that they influenced later philosophers like Peirce and William James.

Comment: This belongs to psychology.SE rather than the history of science as the historical aspect is superficial.

Comment: @MoziburUllah it probably fits in both psych and hsm SEs . Where is conifold when you need him?

Comment: It's more psychology than history ...

Comment: Just mentioning some philosophical people doesn't make it philosophical. It just looks superficial.

Comment: You mean like [associationism about mind](https://iep.utm.edu/associat/) that dominated the scene at the time? It goes back to Locke and Hume, and Peirce reproduces many Humean conceptions and even phrasing ("trains of thought") in, say, [Four Incapacities](http://www.peirce.org/writings/p27.html). James's "stream of consciousness" also has associationist roots. See [Ziak's Associationism in Pragmatism](http://www.klemens.sav.sk/fiusav/filozofia/?q=en/asocianizmus-v-pragmatizme-peirceova-rekonstrukcia-britskeho-empirizmu) on how Peirce transformed associationism into non-mechanistic semiotic.

Comment: @Conifold I am not sure if the associationists speculated on how emotion influences the associations(or ideas and beliefs). The main motivation for this question is my feeling that Peirce's ideas on doubt might have roots on related ideas by earlier philosophers after Kant (coming perhaps from psychophysicists or brain anatomists)

Comment: [Floridi in Scepticism and the Search for Knowledge](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40320487) writes that "*Locke is the first epistemologist who emphasizes the role of uneasiness in the search for knowledge, in this way anticipating some aspects of Peirce's theory of doubt and belief*" citing Essay Concerning Human Understanding, book II, ch. XXI, 1-34. Peirce himself names Bain as the influence, see [Feodorov, Habit Beyond Psychology](https://journals.openedition.org/ejpap/1007):"*Bain is closest to pragmatism and to Peirce in particular when he opposes belief to doubt*".